# pheatmap package different values same colour

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I try to do a Heatmap on R and have four values (1,2,3,4) in my excel file that looks like this

| data | Allgemein | Methode | Ergebnisse | Diskussion | Andere |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 |

I have different values (five times 3 and three times 2) in the category "Methode", but still it gives me only a different color for one of them:

````
pheatmap(df_num,
         main = "Einhaltung von Items der CHEERS 2022 Checkliste nach Kategorien",
         col=brewer.pal(4,"Greens"),
         breaks = seq(1,4),
         fontsize = 12, 
         cluster_rows=F,
         cluster_cols=F,
         cellwidth=20,
         cellheight=20,
         border_color="black", 
         legend_breaks = 1:4, 
         legend_labels = c("100 % erfüllt",
                           "zwischen > 75% und < 100% der Items", 
                           "zwischen >50% und ≤75% der Punkte", 
                           "≤50% der Punkte"))```
````

[image]

Comment: Try `legend.breaks = 0:4 + 0.5`

Comment: does'nt work unfortunately, still looks the same

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I get a correct visualization of your data matrix.

```
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Load data
df_num <- read.table(text="
data Allgemein Methode Ergebnisse Diskussion Andere
1 4 3 2 4 4
2 4 3 2 4 4
3 4 3 2 4 4
4 4 3 2 4 4
5 2 3 2 4 4
6 4 2 3 4 4
7 4 2 2 4 4
8 4 2 1 4 4", header=T, sep=" ")

# Delete the first column; it is only a raw counter
df_num <- df_num[,-1]

pheatmap(df_num,
         main = "Einhaltung von Items der CHEERS 2022 Checkliste nach Kategorien",
         col=brewer.pal(4,"Greens"),
         breaks = seq(1,4),
         fontsize = 12, 
         cluster_rows=F,
         cluster_cols=F,
         cellwidth=20,
         cellheight=20,
         border_color="black", 
         legend_breaks = 1:4, 
         legend_labels = c("100 % erfüllt",
                           "zwischen > 75% und < 100% der Items", 
                           "zwischen >50% und ≤75% der Punkte", 
                           "≤50% der Punkte"))
```

[image]